# ifstream does not read first line

Tags: c++, c++11

I am using the code with `ifstream` that I used ~1 year ago, but now it does not work correctly. Here, I have the following file (so, just a line of integers):

```
2 4 2 3
```

I read it while constructing a graph from this file:

```
graph g = graph("file.txt");
```

where graph constructor starts with:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

graph::graph(const char *file_name) {
    ifstream infile(file_name);
    string line;
    getline(infile, line);
    cout << line << endl; // first output
    istringstream iss;
    iss.str(line);
    iss >> R >> C >> P >> K;
    iss.clear();

    cout << R << " " << C << " " << P << " " << K; // second output
}
```

The second output (marked in code), instead of giving me `2 4 2 3`, returns random(?) values `-1003857504 32689 0 0`. If I add the first output to check the contents of `line` after `getline`, it is just an empty string `""`.

All the files (`main.cpp` where a graph is instantiated, 'graph.cpp' where the graph is implemented and 'file.txt') are located in the same folder.

As I mentioned, this is my old code that worked before, so probably I do not see some obvious mistake which broke it. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Check your IO operations for success/failure. It is done exactly *zero* times in this code. For all you know the file open failed and you never knew it. You said, "...are located in the same folder." - means nothing. The *working directory* set at the time the executable is *running* is what will deem where it looks for the file, and as you've coded it, if the file isn't in said-same, you know nothing about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These two locations:

- where your program's original source code is located
- where your program's input data is located

are *completely unrelated*.

Since "file.txt" is a relative path, your program looks for input data in the *current working directory* during execution. Sometimes that is the same as where the executable is. Sometimes it is not. (Only you can tell what it is, since it depends on how you execute your program.) There is never a connection to the location of the original source file, except possibly by chance.

When the two do not match, you get this problem, because you perform no I/O error checking in your program.

If you checked whether `infile` is open, I bet you'll find that it is not.

This is particularly evident since the program stopped working after a period of time without any changes to its logic; chances are, the only thing that could have changed is the *location* of various elements of your solution.

Comment: You are right indeed. I was using CLion IDE and wrongly assumed that the working directory is automatically set to the project folder once the project is created, which was not the case for some reason.

Comment: Hopefully this is a valuable lesson in building in error checking to your program from the get go! A simple `if (!infile) throw std::runtime_error("Couldn't open file");` would have pointed you to the problem at T=1second, rather than the 4hrs research time + question-asking-time you presumably spent here instead... (plus ours :P)